# Get a comma separated list of entity collection using linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have 2 entities `Line` and `Tag`. The relation is `Line *----* Tag`

From `line` I have a navigation property `Line.Tags` which returns a list of Tag objects. The `Tag.Name` is the string value im after.

What I really need is to get all the tag names in a comma seperated way like so :

```
tag1, tag2, tag3
```

I tried to do this in a projection, but it said it doesnt support `toString()`

```
var o = dgvLines.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as Order;
                var r = _rs.Lines.Where(y => y.InvoiceNo == o.InvoiceNo).Select(x => new
                {
                    ReturnNo = x.Return.ReturnNo,
                    Part = x.Part,
                    Tags = String.Join(", ", x.Tags.ToList().Select(t => t.Name))
                });
                dgvExistingParts.DataSource = r;
```

Error:

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

Any idea how I can get this comma separated list of tags?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var r = _rs.Lines.Where(y => y.InvoiceNo == o.InvoiceNo).ToList().Select(x => new
{
    ReturnNo = x.Return.ReturnNo,
    Part = x.Part,
    Tags = String.Join(", ", x.Tags.Select(t => t.Name))
});
```

Comment: Entity Framework won't support `String.Join`. You'll have to get the names back in a collection and then call `String.Join` after the db call.

Comment: @MuhammadA: Then you can try `x.Tags.AsEnumerable().Select(t => t.Name)` or `_rs.Lines.Where(...).AsEnumerable().Select(...);`

Comment: @MuhammadA: it may have bad impact on performance (you have to check it, I don't know how many records are returned) but try calling ToList() before Select

Comment: @MuhammadA: check my update, I meant ToList() before first Select - I updated the code

Comment: That won't bring any of the `x.Tags` back from the db.

Comment: @NicholasButler: I'm no EF expert but it should work, just not in a single db hit (as I noted above it's not good for performance, however, I usually deal with performance issues when I confirm them)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do the concatenation in SQL, so you have to get back the data you need and then work in normal code:

```
var o = dgvLines.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as Order;

var r = _rs.Lines
  .Where(y => y.InvoiceNo == o.InvoiceNo)
  .Select(x => new
    {
      ReturnNo = x.Return.ReturnNo,
      Part = x.Part,
      TagNames = x.Tags.Select( t => t.Name ),
    }
  )
  .ToList() // this runs the SQL on the database
  .Select( x => new
    {
      ReturnNo = x.ReturnNo,
      Part = x.Part,
      Tags = String.Join( ", ", x.TagNames ),
    }
  )
  .ToList();

  dgvExistingParts.DataSource = r;
```